# Detect when user focuses on document

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I have a chat application for two persons and for example, one of them sends a message to the second one.

When the second one delivers and focuses on document then the browser checks if last element in parent div has class "his_message" and if it does, the browser (via socket.io) sends the message to first user (who sent message) that his partner has seen his message, otherwise: do nothing.

It is like Facebook's "seen" feature when Facebook notifies you that your chat partner has seen your message.

I used MutationObserver for implementing what i want:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations)=>{   
    if(document.hasFocus()){
    console.log($('#output > :last-child').attr('class'));
    socket.emit('seen')
    }
 })

observer.observe(output, { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true });
```

But if you test it, you will know that it is not working like I want. So what can i do to reach my aim? Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for document.onFocus?

Comment: What is the value of `output `?

Comment: @ControlAltDel that is excellent method but problem is that it will emit "seen" everytime document will have focus soo..

Comment: @ksav 
output.innerHTML += `<div class='hisout ${hisclass}'><p class="me">` + encodesMessage + '</p></div>'

this block of code is added dynamically when sending message

Comment: @iLia you don't have to emit "seen" everytime. Within onFocus, do your check that the message is at the end of the document, and only emit if it is

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried this code:` document.onfocus = () =>{
        if($('#output > :last-child').attr('class')){
        socket.emit('seen')}
        }` but it only emits when i send message and also it notifies second user two times

Answer (score -1):

I assume the best way will be to associate easch message with a database column (say: is_seen) where it takes boolean value... once the focus has been made,update the value to True in database...and you can fetch that value to display as seen when the message is clicked just as in messenger app.

Comment: Thank you for advice but it is not what i want